# Некорректное применение css стилей

Tags: html, css

Так я загружаю стили:

```
<head>
<link href="css/A.style.css.pagespeed.cf.X_y49ODPuC.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</head>
***
<style>
*** Мои стили
</style>
```

А в итоге получаю такой результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Всё правильно. [Читайте](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)

Comment: Не понял что ты хочешь получить. Дай более конкретный код

Answer (score 0):

Твои стили применяются к контейнеру и наследуются элементами, находящимися внутри контейнера.

Стили из файла применяются непосредственно к элементу, поэтому перебивают унаследованные стили.

Answer (score -1):

Если идет конфлик стилей, то применяется правило, "кто последний, тот и прав" у вас есть 2 варианта решения данной задачи:

1. прописывать стили перед закрывающимся тегом body
2. это добавить стилю !important, то-бишь так color: #fcffff!important;